# asp.net mvc duplicate parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters

i have 2 link on page PictureList

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("pic", "PictureList", "Admin")%>
```

and

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("pic", "PictureList", "Admin", new { id = item.MenuId })%>
```

after click on second link, first link catch id parameter. how can it be solved?

Comment: How is your controller setup? Can you post your controller code?  And the same for your routes....

Comment: controller is simple, routing default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your link's redirecting to same action. So you may want to assign the value of id

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("pic", "PictureList", "Admin", new { id = 0 })%>
```

Comment: it works only if i use this code
<%= Html.ActionLink("Картинки", "PictureList", "Admin", new { id = 0 }, null)%>
in other case id add parameter ?Length=5

Comment: I didnt understood what you want to say but i guess length is a parameter, did you bind it in routing?